# Brain attributes and ipdb autocomplete

Tags: plone

Why ipdb session don't show every attribute of a brain with autocomplete?
For example brain.UID exists but it is not listed on ipdb autocomplete.
Is it any black magic on brain code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ipdb you can autocomplete all attributes of a brain:

```
>>> dir(brain)
['__add__', '__allow_access_to_unprotected_subobjects__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__implemented__', '__init__', '__len__', '__module__', '__mul__', '__new__', '__of__', '__providedBy__', '__provides__', '__record_schema__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_unrestrictedGetObject', 'getObject', 'getPath', 'getRID', 'getURL', 'has_key']
```

The metadata of a brain is not directly stored on the "brain". They are stored in a Btree (`data`attribute) on the Catalog. You can access all informations stored in the data storage `through` the brain.

So if you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist on the brain it will try to return the value from the metadata storage if the key is available, otherwise `AttributeError`is raised.

The magic happens somewhere [here (ZCatalog)](https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.ZCatalog/blob/b0abb6fea8307d624c3a7f3725791d0163b2d472/src/Products/ZCatalog/Catalog.py#L142).

Also check line 77:

> # The catalog maintains a BTree of object meta_data for
>      convenient display on result pages.  meta_data attributes
>      are turned into brain objects and returned by
>      searchResults.

In the ZMI on the `portal_catalog` tool, there' a `metadata` tab, which shows all accessible metadata infos.

Update:

**Playing around with the catalog:**

```
>>> plone = app.Plone
>>> catalog = plone.portal_catalog
>>> _catalog = catalog._catalog
>>> brain = catalog()[0]

# Metadata are stored in the data BTree, key is the RID of the brain.
>>> rid = brain.getRID()
>>> rid
704953343

>>> _catalog.data
<BTrees.IOBTree.IOBTree object at 0x10b158150>

>>> _catalog.data[rid]
# The UID is part of this tuple.
('2015-07-22T09:27:09+02:00', 'admin', '2015-07-22T15:12:07+02:00', '', 'None', 'None', '2015-07-22T15:12:07+02:00', (), 'xxx', u'xxx', '38e87a4b80704681b60781b66d37346c', DateTime('2015/07/22 09:27:9.236886 GMT+2'), DateTime('1969/12/31 00:00:00 GMT+2'), Missing.Value, Missing.Value, DateTime('2499/12/31 00:00:00 GMT+2'), '', 'xxx', '0 KB', Missing.Value, 'xxx', True, ('admin',), Missing.Value, 'Dexterity Container', DateTime('2015/07/22 15:12:7.787001 GMT+2'), 'xxx', Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 0, None, (), Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value)
```

Comment: hi @Mathias, thank you for your post, I learned a lot, but I'm not making your answer as the right one because `dir(brain)` don't show all attributes (UID is not there)

Comment: is there a way to access the metadata stored in the Btree with an ipdb session?

Comment: Well, the UID is also no an attribute on the brain, it's an index and therefore only accessible through the brain.

Comment: Yes you can debug: `_catalog = plonesite.portal_catalog._catalog`, now _catalog has a attribute `data`, which holds all metadata infos to all brains. btw. key is the RID of a brain.

Comment: brain.schema() does the trick :)

    ipdb> brain.schema()
    ['Title', 'exclude_from_nav', 'Type', 'id', 'end', 'Description', 'listCreators', 'is_folderish', 'getId', 'start', 'ExpirationDate', 'Date', 'review_state', 'getRemoteUrl', 'location', 'EffectiveDate', 'portal_type', 'expires', 'ModificationDate', 'getObjSize', 'UID', 'effective', 'Creator', 'getIcon', 'created', 'modified', 'meta_type', 'CreationDate', 'Subject']